# How to sort files in folder by date created?

Tags: google-drive

Is there a way to sort files in a folder by the date of their creation?

I'm trying to figure out in which order my documents were created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [Google Support Page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375177?hl=en) it appears there is no way currently to search by date of creation.

The support page only explains that the following methods are supported:

- Last edited by me
- Last modified
- Last opened by me
- Title
- Quota used

Comment: 10 years later...but there is a workaround: if you install Google Drive (for mac or windows) it creates a local folder that can be sorted by Created Date

Answer (score 2):

Now the problem has been solved!
Below I copied the solution found in the [forums, here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/2511128?hl=en&msgid=7951061):

> If you click on Last Modified column, a popup shows up where you can
> select Last Modified, Last Modified by me or Last Opened by me. But if
> you want to sort by any of them, you have to click to the right of the
> popup menu arrow between that field and the next one to the right
> (believe me). If you're lucky, another arrow appears that allows you
> to sort by ascending or descending order. This will change for sure
> but today is how it works in Chrome on Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to view google photos sorted by date added - 
[google photos](https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_)

(from: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/photos/bfl_TDq-NpM/z6rJ2m-8EgAJ)

Comment: I'm not even sure this is a difficult problem to solve, 4.5 years later, but thank you for your answer anyways :p