# Sort Google Drive by date added

Tags: sorting, google-drive

Is there a way to sort Google Drive (either iOS or web version) by date that a file was added?

It drives me crazy that if I use Gmail to save an attachment to Drive, I can't locate that file immediately unless I know the name of the file (and then have to search it). Because 99% of time when I add a file to drive I want to access it immediately, and the easiest way to do that would be if I could sort drive by "date added".

Right now I only see a way to sort by "title" and "last modified" (same as recent). But most of the time when you add a file, it wasn't necessarily modified recently, so sorting by recent does not help at all.

Comment: Check this similar discussion http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47582/how-to-sort-files-in-folder-by-date-created

Answer (score 1):

Your [options for sorting](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375177) are:

- **Last edited by me**
  Ordered by when you last made changes to your files
- **Last modified**
  Ordered by when any user made changes to your files
- **Last opened by me**
  Ordered by when you last opened your files
- **Name**
  Ordered by title of your files in alphabetical order

[image: Google Drive sort options]

It seems to me that "Last opened by me" is what you're probably after. There isn't an explicit "added to Google Drive" value